# Pick list items in VSTS gets auto sorted

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to add some items (strings) to a pick list in VSTS. The items get auto sorted alphabetically (ascending order).

Below is the scenario:

[image: Link for the Pick list]

I entered 'test' then 'abc' and then 'xyz', but it auto sorts and displays 'abc' then 'test' and then 'xyz'.

Is there any way to avoid this sorting and the items should be inserted in the order they were entered?

And I want to achieve this without writing an extension.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the values for the picklist (string) Type field can only ordered by alphabet so far.

But there has an user voice [Custom Sort Order for TFS Fields](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2127879-custom-sort-order-for-tfs-fields) (for VSTS, added in comment) about customzing sort order for fields, and you can vote and follow up.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using VSTS, you cannot avoid the sorting or have your own sorting for a list field.